# Mono-D DMD compiler issues

Tags: monodevelop, d, dmd

With features like Code Completion and simple refactoring, writing D in Mono-D is almost as productive as writing C# in Visual Studios. Everything works great on Linux, just install Mono Develop, add the Mono-D repository, and build; but on Windows I can't even get the Hello World to compile.

At first It seems DMD can't find Phobos, but after following instructions on the [Getting Started Page](http://mono-d.sourceforge.net/?page_id=11) I get 21 errors in the *Object.di* file. Errors like ***"found 'char' when expecting ')'"*** and ***"no identifier for declarator immutable"***.

I'm using Mono Develop 2.8.5 on Windows 7 64bit.

Anyone have a clue as to how I can get this working?

Comment: I never used Mono-D - seems nice, but Mono is not my cup of tea to be honest...

Comment: @DejanLekic MonoDevelop is the best IDE for Linux IMO. Geany and Gedit are great, but MD has the best project management for a bunch of languages. Really the only thing I don't like about it is that it doesn't have syntax highlighting on operator characters (wtf right?). Maybe they added that in 2.9 I dunno.

Comment: I am not that impressed to be honest. But on the other hand I did not use it for more than 20min. I use Code::Blocks for D coding most of the time. There is also Eclipse DDT which constantly improves, but I never liked it either. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My mistake. It looks like DMD wasn't installed correctly. I uninstalled DMD, then re-installed it (without D1) and everything works now.

Comment: you could have just removed the path to the D1 install from the %PATH% environment variable (`dmd -version` would have told you you were using the D1 compiler)

Comment: I'm not sure it was a D1 issue. I think druntime didn't update property when I went to 2.057.

Comment: nah if you install both D1 and D2 both the compiler paths are added to the %path% with the D1 path first and windows goes in order so when you put in `dmd mymodule.d` it'll first check `C:\path\to\install\dir\dmd\windows\bin\` and uses the dmd.exe there instead of the dmd in `C:\path\to\install\dir\dmd2\windows\bin\` which is the one you want to use